# c# - opencvsharp : How can i change MatExpr to Mat

Tags: c#, opencv

```
        Mat a = new Mat(3, 1, MatType.CV_8UC1);
        Mat b = new Mat(1,3, MatType.CV_8UC1);

        for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        {
            a.Set<byte>(i, 0, (byte)i);
            b.Set<byte>(0, i, (byte)(i + 3));
        }
        var c = a * b;  
        mat = c.ToMat(); // error
```

result of a.Mul(b) is MatExpr class 
i want to create 3x3 matrix.
how can i make it Mat Class?

Answer (score -1):

self answer : matrix multiplication of Opencv supports double type only.
If you want to calculate in Byte format, see this.

```
        Mat a = new Mat(3, 1, MatType.CV_64FC1, new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 });
        Mat b = new Mat(1, 3, MatType.CV_64FC1, new double[] { 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 });
        Mat c = new Mat(3, 3, MatType.CV_64FC1);


        var c = (a * b).ToMat();
        c.ConvertTo(c, MatType.CV_8UC1);
        Trace.WriteLine(c.At<byte>(0,0)); // 4
```